# Underlying abelian group of coproduct of commutative rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings (we assume) we can construct their coproduct $A \sqcup B$ with the inclusion maps $i_a$ and $i_b$. I'm trying to show that this coproduct has underlying abelian group $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$, without showing that the tensor product just is the coproduct.

That is, I'm trying to show that the underlying abelian group is the tensor product without just defining the obvious ring structure on it and showing that by uniqueness it just is the coproduct.

So far, I've shown that there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear map 
$$
i : A \times B \to A\sqcup B, i(a,b) = i_A(a)i_B(b),
$$
then this gives us a map from the tensor product $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B \to A \sqcup B$, and I'm pretty sure this is the `right' map to look at, I just can't see how to construct an inverse.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You have to use _something_ about commutative rings. After all, it is not true for non-commutative rings. If you want a general result, you might try to prove the analogue for commutative algebras in a symmetric monoidal category...

Comment: Yeah, I agree, could you give me a hint as to where I want to use the commutativity though?

Comment: You need it to show that there is a multiplication on the tensor product.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was trying to show it without doing that, but you're right, it seems impossible